# Making algorithms display after the paragraph and split them in pages

Tags: page-breaking, algorithms

I am using `algorithmicx` to write algorithms. I want to be able to write algorithms so that they appear right after the paragraph they have been written and possibly split them from the end of one page to the starting of the next page if the space is not sufficient.

How to do so?

Comment: Please add a MWE.

Answer (score 6):

To break down your post, you want:

1. To have an algorithm appear immediately after a paragraph in which it was discussed; and
2. To have the algorithm split across pages (if possible).

In order to fulfill **both** requests, you cannot place your `algorithmicx` environment within an `algorithm` environment, since the latter is a float. And, floats move around. Moreover, floats do not break over pages. So, you'll have to make your own environment that accounts for an algorithm caption and number. Here is a very basic example of what that would entail:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{xifthen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen
\usepackage{needspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

% ================ ALGORITHM ENVIRONMENT ================
\newcounter{myalg}% Algorithm counter
\newenvironment{myalg}[1][]%
  {% \begin{myalg}[#1]
    \needspace{2\baselineskip}% At least 2\baselineskip required, otherwise break
    \noindent \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} \endgraf% Top rule
    \refstepcounter{myalg}% For correct reference of algorithm
    \centering \textsc{Algorithm}~\themyalg%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{:\ #1}% Typeset name (if provided)
  }{% \end{myalg}
  \noindent \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}% Bottom rule
  }%

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

Here is Algorithm~\ref{first-alg}:

\begin{myalg}[My first algorithm]
\label{first-alg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \State This is some code
 \State This is some more code
 \State Here is some code
 \State This is some code
 \State This is some more code
 \State Here is some code
 \State This is some code
 \State This is some more code
 \State Here is some code
 \State This is some code
 \State This is some more code
 \State Here is some code
\end{algorithmic}
\end{myalg}

That was Algorithm~\ref{first-alg}.

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

In the above example, the `myalg` environment does not float and replaces the original `algorithm` environment. As an optional argument, `myalg` will typeset a caption. The [`xifthen` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen) provides a conditional clause to check for a caption or not. The [`needspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) conditions on the amount of space left on the page. In order to not be stuck with a rule or caption at the page bottom, `needspace` will issue a `\break` if there is less then `2\baselineskip` left on the page. The [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) was also included to show you that the hyperlinks work properly, while the [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides dummy text.

[image]

If you're into a more vibrant array of decorations for your algorithms, then the [`mdframed` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) allows easy breaking of decorative frames across pages:

[image]

This can be extended to include items into a "List of Algorithms" as well.