# Continued Algorithm over 2 pages

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I have a long algorithm that's taking three quarter of a page and so it's taking a whole page with an empty quarter. I want it to be continued with the previous text without leaving any empty place, that means that it will be divided into two pages.

I found answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29816/algorithm-over-2-pages) that allow to divide the algorithm into two previously set parts, however, I want the algorithm to dynamically fit into the two pages. How I can do that?

Here is an example of the situation that I am having:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\linespread{1.15}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
Qu’est que c’est?. C’est une phrase fran ̧cais avant le lorem ipsum. Loremipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisissem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet minec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultricesaugue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut,ultricies vel, semper in, velit.
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{XXX}\label{alg:ChainProcess}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State \textbf{Entrées:} XXX
\State \textbf{Sortie:} XXX
\State XXX

\For{\texttt{(\textit{i allant de 1 à (T-1)})}}
    \State  XXX

    \For{\texttt{( XXX}}
        \State \textit{XXX}XXX
        \For{\texttt{(XXX)}}        
            \If{XXX)}

                \State \textit{XXX} XXX
                \State XXX

            \EndIf

        \EndFor

        \If{(XXX) } 
            \State xXX
        \EndIf
    \EndFor 
    %\State 
\EndFor 

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33866/80972

Comment: Alternatively this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/making-algorithms-display-after-the-paragraph-and-split-them-in-pages/27422#27422 works for me.

Comment: @Arzigoglu this has solved it.